# Setting relation values in a nested TYPO3 Extbase Backendform

Tags: typo3, extbase, flexform

Suppose I have this database model in extbase:

model A 
    - property
    - n:1 relation to model B

model B
    - property
    - n:1 relation to model C

model C
    - property

Can I achieve something like this in the backend form of model A?

instance of model B 1
    [] good [] bad

instance of model B 2
    [] good [] bad

and so on.

Short, I want to set the values for the property of model C in the form of model A for all instances of model B. Is there a way to do this in the TCA configuration or with a nested flexform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Although I think you want to do that in Model C (or I misunderstood you or 1,n are mixed up). I assume C 1<=>n B 1<=>n A.

Have a look at the `inline` column type https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html, also referred to as "IRRE" (inline relational something). This allows to create and edit sub-records inline. Check out the column types `group` and `select`, too. They are suitable for 1..n:n relations, too.

This works in TCA and Flexform (for Model C). Persistence IIRC in IRRE must be done to the DB (as opposed to a flexform string like e.g. `tt_content.pi_flexform`), so Model B and A should be TCA-defined and have tables.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Perhaps the description of my models were a bit misleading.

The aim is, that every Instance of B belongs/is assigned to A initially when an Instance of B is created and in A I can set the property "[] good [] bad" for every instance of B with a radio form. 

Perhaps relations between A and B respectively B and C are not really needed. Every B should "belong" to all As and C only should store the options for the radio form.

So I need a solution to make a selection between the properties in the radio for every B like in a questionnaire.

Comment: So imagine A ist the questionnaire, B are the questions an C are the possible answers.

Therefore I thought about storing the selection in a flexform, but I don't see, how I can get B and C in the flexform sheet in a nested mannor.  

Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: B and C need to be in the database and defined by TCA. Then A in a Flexform can hold B and C. Please accept the answer if you find it helpful.